# Pass parameters to an xsl template

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Im making a call to an xsl template in which im constructing a table. i want to conditionally set the color of the table depending on the value in the param. Any suggestions ?

Ex.

```
<xsl:template match="sometemplate">
    <xsl:param name="bgcolor" select="'black'"/>
    <table>
        <!-- I have to set the background color of this tr depending on the value of bgcolor -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- Do Something -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="callingTemplate">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sometemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="bgcolor" select="'white'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Attribute Value Template here. Replace `<tr>` with this:

```
<tr style="background-color:{$bgcolor}">
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally, and so it will be replaced with whatever colour name you pass to the template. For example:

```
<tr style="background-color:white">
```